# GPS position detection through java applet in site

Tags: mobile, applet, gps, mobile-website

We want to include java applet in site that will be visited by mobile phone, and that applect will detect GPS position and send it to server.
Is it possible?

Comment: java applet on a mobile site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Geolocation API in Javascript. Pretty much all mobile browsers support it so you don't need to use a Java applet.

http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/

Comment: How does they define geolocation? By using GPS, or by WiFi points?

Comment: It depends on what's available on the device.